# Setting nvidia properties during X-server startup

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia

I am using the proprietary nvidia drivers in KDE (Debian Testing) and as many others experience issues with performance. I noticed that it gets a bit better if I run:

```
nvidia-settings -a InitialPixmapPlacement=0
```

at least with Google Chrome.

How can I add this to the standard start-up configuration? I tried adding an option to `xorg.conf` and I tried adding this line to a newly created `.xinitrc`, but it didn't work. Where should I have it added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `~/.nvidia-settings-rc`, add a line (or change it, if it is there with a different value) like this:

```
0/InitialPixmapPlacement=0
```

and have

```
nvidia-settings --load-config-only`
```

executed on your *session startup* [(some details)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting#Graphical).  How to set this is desktop environment-dependent and only in the basic case (say, using a minimal or self-configured desktop environment) done via `~/.xinitrc`.

I don't know about the details with KDE, [but here's some blog post describing it](http://linuxlibrary.org/managing-startup-applications-kubuntu-systems/), it's somewhere under system settings.